# Get Words out of a Trie Data Structure

Tags: java, search, trie

i have the following Trie Data Structure:

```
public class CDictionary implements IDictionary {

private static final int N = 'z' -'a'+1;

private static class Node {
    private boolean end = false;
    private Node[] next = new Node[N];
}

private int size = 0;
private Node root = new Node();

@Override
public boolean contains(String word) {
    Node node = this.contains(root,word,0);
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return node.end;
}

private Node contains(Node node, String str, int d) {
    if (node == null) return null;
    if (d == str.length()) return node;

    char c = str.charAt(d);
    return contains(node.next[c-'a'], str, d+1);
}

@Override
public void insert(String word) {
    this.root = insert(this.root, word, 0);
    this.size++;
}

private Node insert(Node node, String str, int d) {
    if (node == null) node = new Node();
    if (d == str.length()) {
        node.end = true;
        return node;
    }

    char c = str.charAt(d);
    node.next[c-'a'] = this.insert(node.next[c-'a'], str, d+1);
    return node;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

The Trie is filled with some words like

> for, the, each, home, is, it, egg, red...

Now i need a function to get all Words with a specific length for example the length 3

```
public List<String> getWords(int lenght) {

}
```

With the Words mentioned above it should return a list with the words

> for,the,egg,red

The Problem is how can i restore these words out of the Trie Structur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recurse through your structure to a maximum depth of N (in this case 3)

You could do this by adding a couple of methods to your dictionary...

```
public List<String> findWordsOfLength(int length) {
    // Create new empty list for results
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    // Start at the root node (level 0)...
    findWordsOfLength(root, "", 0, length, results);
    // Return the results
    return results;
}

public void findWordsOfLength(Node node, String wordSoFar, int depth, int maxDepth, List<String> results) {
    // Go through each "child" of this node
    for(int k = 0; k < node.next.length; k++) {
       Node child = node.next[k];
       // If this child exists...
       if(child != null) {
           // Work out the letter that this child represents
           char letter = 'a' + k;
           // If we have reached "maxDepth" letters...
           if(depth == maxDepth) {
               // Add this letter to the end of the word so far and then add the word to the results list
               results.add(wordSoFar + letter);
           } else {
               // Otherwise recurse to the next level
               findWordsOfLength(child, wordSoDar + letter, depth + 1, maxDepth, results);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

(I have not compiled / tested this, but it should give you an idea of what you need to do)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, this might find words of length "4" when "3" is passed in, like I said, not tested it... You might also have to check that the last node is terminal (i.e. do not add it to the result list unless all of it's child nodes are empty...)

Comment: Thank you this did work. I have solved the problems with the word length. I start the Recursive Method with a Depth of 1